# Why locally compact and why Hausdorff in the definition of $C_0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Define a set $C_0(\Omega)$ to be the set of continuous functions $f:\Omega \to \mathbb C$ such that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ the set $\{\omega \in \Omega | |f(\omega)|\ge \varepsilon \}$ is compact. Here $\Omega$ is locally compact (or even compact) and Hausdorff. (see for example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_functions_on_a_compact_Hausdorff_space))

What will go wrong if $\Omega$ is not locally compact but Hausdorff and what will go wrong if $\Omega$ is not Hausdorff but locally compact?